# How do I to flush redis db from python redis?

Tags: python, redis

Is there a way I can flush my redis db using [redis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis/)?

I'm looking for something like `redis.flushdb()` or `redis.flushall()`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Redis-py actually has this functionality:

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis()
r.flushdb()
```

Answer (score 23):

Yes, `flushdb()` and `flushall()` both exist.

check out this [page](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.Redis.flushall), you will find them.

Answer (score 6):

You can try also.

```
r.execute_command('FLUSHALL ASYNC') # delete keys in background
```

> FLUSHALL ASYNC (Redis 4.0.0 or greater)

Redis is now able to delete keys in the background in a different thread without blocking the server. An ASYNC option was added to FLUSHALL and FLUSHDB in order to let the entire dataset or a single database to be freed asynchronously.

```
r.flushdb() # Delete all keys of currently selected database instance.
r.flushall() # Delete all keys of entire database.
```

---

Further reading
: [Redis FLUSHALL ASYNC](https://redis.io/commands/flushall)